# Как асинхронно вызвать синхронный метод?

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, rabbitmq

Насколько я понимаю в текущей реализации библиотеки RabbitMQ.Client (https://www.nuget.org/packages/RabbitMQ.Client/) для c# нет асинхронного варианта для метода `BasicPublish`.
Я хотел бы что бы вызов этого метода был асинхронный что бы не блокировать потоки.

Я написал вот обёртку но не уверен в том что сделал это правильно, подскажите кто знает:

```cs
Exception exception = null;
await Task.Run(() => { 
    try {
        _channel.BasicPublish("", basicProperties.ReplyTo, replyProps, content);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        exception = e;
    } 
});
if(exception != null) {
    throw exception;
}
```

Comment: Последняя реализация похожа на то что нужно, можно даже без фигурных скобок в одну строчку.

Comment: Вы можете сами ответить на свой вопрос, а затем принять ответ, при этом рекомендуется удалить ответ из вопроса. Еще раз поясню, что то, к чему вы пришли - правильный способ сделать то что вам нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Немного полистав интернет пришёл к такой реализации:

```cs
return Task.Run(() => 
    _channel.BasicPublish("", basicProperties.ReplyTo, replyProps, content);
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Все то же самое, но без await. Можно так же сначала создать поток, потом его запустить:

```
    Task task = new Task(() => { 
        try {
            _channel.BasicPublish("", basicProperties.ReplyTo, replyProps, content);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exception = e;
        } 
    });

   task.Start();
```